# How to concat two Expression<BigDecimal> in Query Builder Api for Java?

Tags: java, concatenation, query-builder

I have two Expression. One contains first part of number, the second one second part. I want to concat these two parts together. As I see in documentation for javax.persistance.criteria.QueryBuilder concat can be done only on Expression. Is there any chance to concat these values?

```
Expression<BigDecimal> one = root.get(ClassName_.decimalValue1);
Expression<BigDecimal> two = root.get(ClassName_.decimalValue2);
predicatesList.add(criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.concat(one, two).in(array)));
```

Comment: how about converting into string and then use +

Comment: When converting to string?

Comment: Once you got the value convert it into string and then concat both the strings

Comment: You mean cast Expression<BigDecimal> to String? Or value in root.get? Then what about predicates?

Comment: I believe `Expression<BigDecimal>` is a number right ?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand where should I use toString method